# Map object to string expression

Tags: javascript

The following fixed expression and values need to be changed to dynamic:

```js
function update(args) {
  const params = {
    UpdateExpression: 'set firstName = :firstName, lastName = :lastName, sex = :sex',
    // values map to UpdateExpression
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':firstName': args.firstName,
      ':lastName': args.lastName,
      ':sex': args.sex
    }
  };

  // db specific code, not relevant
}
```

It currently only works with fixed arguments, for example:

```
update({firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Doe', sex: 'M'}
```

I need the `UpdateExpression` and `ExpressionAttributeValues` to dynamically change with more or less arguments, *e.g*:

1. `args` also has `height: 190`
2. add `height = :height` to `UpdateExpression` (and comma)
3. add `':height': args.height` to `ExpressionAttributeValues`

---

How should I parse that expression and how should I deal with the commas?

---

#### What I've got:

Expression string generation seems awkward and I have problems with commas.

```js
const args = {
  id: 'id-123',
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  updated: 1491111234
};

function update(args) {
  console.log('===');
  expression = 'set ';
  values = {};

  for (let variable in args) {
    // expression string
    let str = `${variable} = :${variable}, `;
    console.log(str);
    expression = expression.concat(str);

    // values object
    values[`:${variable}`] = args[variable];
  }

  console.log('---');
  console.log('UpdateExpression:', expression);
  console.log('ExpressionAttributeValues:', values);
  console.log('===');
}

update(args);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a way of determining when to add a comma, which should be every time except for the last. So you could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the keys of the object and do a standard `for` loop to check if it's the last one.

```js
const args = {
  id: 'id-123',
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  updated: 1491111234
};

function update(args) {
  console.log('===');
  expression = 'set ';
  values = {};
  
  const keys = Object.keys(args);
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    const key = keys[i];
    const value = args[key];
    const str = `${key} = :${key}`;
    console.log(str);
    expression += str;
    values[`:${key}`] = value;
    if (i < keys.length - 1) {
      expression += ', ';
    }
  }

  console.log('---');
  console.log('UpdateExpression:', expression);
  console.log('ExpressionAttributeValues:', values);
  console.log('===');
}

update(args);
```